# Copy a directory to a different drive

Tags: c#

How do I copy a directory to a different drive in C#?

Comment: lol, what? Sorry not making fun of anyone just thought this question is hilarious the way it is asked :)

Comment: I understand that the question has been answered, but you should try and improve the quality of the question. It's not very well written.

Comment: I think we need a new reason to close - 'easy to find if the OP makes the effort'

Comment: i I have checked your 'user details' and found that you are new, I don't want demoralize you because same thing happened with me, when I was new to stackoverflow, this is really very good community for programmers, You just first try to search topics on google and if you not found any solution their, then only put your question here, also put the code which you have written to do this task(if you have).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use this code to perform your operation:

```
public static  void CopyAll(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target)
{
    // Check if the target directory exists, if not, create it.
    if (Directory.Exists(target.FullName) == false)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(target.FullName);
    }

    // Copy each file into it’s new directory.
    foreach (FileInfo fi in source.GetFiles())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(@”Copying {0}\{1}”, target.FullName, fi.Name);
        fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.ToString(), fi.Name), true);
    }

    // Copy each subdirectory using recursion.
    foreach (DirectoryInfo diSourceSubDir in source.GetDirectories())
    {
        DirectoryInfo nextTargetSubDir =
            target.CreateSubdirectory(diSourceSubDir.Name);
        CopyAll(diSourceSubDir, nextTargetSubDir);
    }
}
```

below one is also good:

```
    static public void CopyFolder( string sourceFolder, string destFolder )
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists( destFolder ))
            Directory.CreateDirectory( destFolder );
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles( sourceFolder );
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            string name = Path.GetFileName( file );
            string dest = Path.Combine( destFolder, name );
            File.Copy( file, dest );
        }
        string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories( sourceFolder );
        foreach (string folder in folders)
        {
           string name = Path.GetFileName( folder );
           string dest = Path.Combine( destFolder, name );
            CopyFolder( folder, dest );
        }
    }
```

you can use this function also:

```
FileSystem.CopyDirectory(sourceDir, destDir);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
FileSystem.CopyDirectory(sourceDir, destDir);
```

[`FileSystem.CopyDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127957.aspx?PHPSESSID=gmkmem7inohg2q677fst152mr6) is in a VB namespace and assembly, but that probably doesn't matter.

Comment: @Crash893 Yes it does.

Comment: @KyleDelaney yes it does now (its been 7 years since I posted this)

Comment: @Crash893 7 years since Matthew posted this. 5 years since you did.

Answer (score 2):

**How to: Copy, Delete, and Move Files and Folders (C# Programming Guide)** 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994.aspx

**C# Copy Folder Recursively**
http://www.csharp411.com/c-copy-folder-recursively/

Answer (score 2):

Here's an extension that will work in .NET 4.0+

```
var source = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Test");
var destination = new DirectoryInfo(@"E:\Test");
source.CopyTo(destination);
```

Include this file in your project

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace System.IO
{
  public static class DirectoryInfoExtensions
  {
    public static void CopyTo(this DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target)
    {
      if (!target.Exists)
        target.Create();

      foreach (var file in source.GetFiles())
        file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.FullName, file.Name), true);

      foreach (var subdir in source.GetDirectories())
        subdir.CopyTo(target.CreateSubdirectory(subdir.Name));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private String path;
    public int copyAllContents(String destinationFolder, ProgressBar progressBar)
    {
        int countCopyFiles = 0;
        if (!Directory.Exists(destinationFolder))
        { Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationFolder); }
        String[] allFilesForCurrentFolder = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        String[] subFoldersAllpath = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
        for (int i = 0; i < allFilesForCurrentFolder.Length; i++)
        {
            try { File.Copy(allFilesForCurrentFolder[i], destinationFolder + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(allFilesForCurrentFolder[i])); countCopyFiles++; progressBar.Value++; }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString()); }
        }
        if (subFoldersAllpath.Length == 0)
        { return allFilesForCurrentFolder.Length; };
        for (int i = 0; i < subFoldersAllpath.Length; i++)
        {
            this.path = subFoldersAllpath[i];
            String[] subFoldersAllpathLastFolder = subFoldersAllpath[i].Split('\\');
            countCopyFiles += this.copyAllContents(destinationFolder + "\\" + subFoldersAllpathLastFolder[subFoldersAllpathLastFolder.Length - 1], progressBar);
        }
        return countCopyFiles;
    }
```

Comment: It is much easier for others to read your answer if you format your code properly. Also, it is best to add some context to your code. Write about why you think this is a good answer or what it does differently than the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that copies a directory recursively as an `async` function:

```
public static async Task CopyDirectoryAsync(string sourceDirectory, string destinationDirectory)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(destinationDirectory))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationDirectory);

    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory))
    {
        var name = Path.GetFileName(file);
        var dest = Path.Combine(destinationDirectory, name);
        await CopyFileAsync(file, dest);
    }

    foreach (var subdir in Directory.GetDirectories(sourceDirectory))
    {
        var name = Path.GetFileName(subdir);
        var dest = Path.Combine(destinationDirectory, name);
        await CopyDirectoryAsync(subdir, dest);
    }
}

public static async Task CopyFileAsync(string sourceFile, string destinationFile)
{
    using (var sourceStream = new FileStream(sourceFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 4096, FileOptions.Asynchronous | FileOptions.SequentialScan))
    using (var destinationStream = new FileStream(destinationFile, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 4096, FileOptions.Asynchronous | FileOptions.SequentialScan))
        await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(destinationStream);
}
```