# "Move will not work across volumes" - Why? And how to overcome?

Tags: c#, file, directory

Why is it that `File.Move(sourceFileName, destFileName)` works fine when the source file and destination files are in different partitions, but `Directory.Move(sourceDirName, destDirName)` don't? It throws

> System.IO.IOException: "Source and destination path must have
>   identical roots. Move will not work across volumes."

I even tried to create a `DirectoryInfo` instance and use the `MoveTo(destDirName)` method but without success.

Am I missing something? Do I really have to implement a "move" functionality myself? (the directory I want to move is very large btw).

Comment: Its because it uses this native API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ***The one caveat is that the MoveFile function will fail on directory moves when the destination is on a different volume.*** I would `Process.Start` XCopy and redirect standard output to monitor the process, especially with large directories.

Comment: I see it as a probable implementation oversight that `File.Move` does work, but `Directory.Move` doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also p/invoke [`SHFileOperation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is the same function Windows Explorer uses to move directories around.  It will either perform a true move or recursive-copy-then-delete, as appropriate.

It can also show the same progress UI as explorer, just by setting a flag.

Comment: @firsttimer: pinvoke.net is great for calling Win32 APIs: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/SHFileOperation.html

Comment: Thanks. I'm giving it a try.

Comment: This seems to preserve the creation date when I move from C: to a USB stick, but then it uses a new date when I move from a USB stick to the C: drive. Do you know why?

Comment: @KyleDelaney is the USB drive using the same filesystem as the C: drive?

Comment: @Marc.2377 - I have no way of checking a USB stick from 2 years ago

Answer (score 14):

You should Use [Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc148994(v=vs.100).aspx) Function followed by a remove. As [Move](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move(v=vs.110).aspx) only works in the same drive.
`Directory.Move` has a condition that states that :

> > **IO Exception** will be thrown if an attempt was made to move a directory to a different volume.

Comment: Suppose you don't want to change the directory's creation date.

Comment: Also, your `Copy` link is broken. Was there a `Directory.Copy` function at some point?

Answer (score 6):

Another option is, to add a reference to the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace and use the `MoveDirectory` method, which can move across volumes.

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.MoveDirectory(sourceDirName, destDirName);
```

Comment: I tried it and it didn't preserve the creation date, so I'm guessing it's still doing a copy/delete behind the scenes.

Answer (score 3):

Although this is not a Vb.Net question but I found no one mentioned this method so I think might help... Only you need to convert it to C# if needed.

Code:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveDirectory(SrcDir,DestDir)
```

This works on different volume seamlessly/ per my experience.

Comment: This was the simplest and best solution in my opinion. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @MousaAlfhaily you are welcome and I am happy it helped you :)

Comment: Very very very thanks! I was struggling with this since weeks thinking on how to move across drives. This was the easiest and worked perfectly! Thanks a million. I wish I could upvote for this answer `n`  number of times. Sad that I could do it only once

Comment: @Priya I am glad it helped you. And thank you so much for the kind words, means a lot! 

- `Happy Coding!`

Answer (score 3):

Based on the posts "[Copy a directory to a different drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947300/copy-a-directory-to-a-different-drive)" and "[Non-recursive way to get all files in a directory and its subdirectories in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776252/non-recursive-way-to-get-all-files-in-a-directory-and-its-subdirectories-in-java)", I wrote this non-recursive method and it works fine:

```
public static void Move(string source, string target)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(source))
        {
            throw new System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException("Source directory couldn't be found.");
        }

        if (Directory.Exists(target))
        {
            throw new System.IO.IOException("Target directory already exists.");
        }

        DirectoryInfo sourceInfo = Directory.CreateDirectory(source);
        DirectoryInfo targetInfo = Directory.CreateDirectory(target);

        if (sourceInfo.FullName == targetInfo.FullName)
        {
            throw new System.IO.IOException("Source and target directories are the same.");
        }

        Stack<DirectoryInfo> sourceDirectories = new Stack<DirectoryInfo>();
        sourceDirectories.Push(sourceInfo);

        Stack<DirectoryInfo> targetDirectories = new Stack<DirectoryInfo>();
        targetDirectories.Push(targetInfo);

        while (sourceDirectories.Count > 0)
        {
            DirectoryInfo sourceDirectory = sourceDirectories.Pop();
            DirectoryInfo targetDirectory = targetDirectories.Pop();

            foreach (FileInfo file in sourceDirectory.GetFiles())
            {
                file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(targetDirectory.FullName, file.Name), overwrite: true);
            }

            foreach(DirectoryInfo subDirectory in sourceDirectory.GetDirectories())
            {
                sourceDirectories.Push(subDirectory);
                targetDirectories.Push(targetDirectory.CreateSubdirectory(subDirectory.Name));
            }
        }

        sourceInfo.Delete(true);
    }
```

Comment: Beautiful work there. Works out of the box, but had to comment the 


```if (Directory.Exists(target))
        {
            throw new System.IO.IOException("Target directory already exists.");
        }```

in my case

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is a little old... but there is a way around this!  Don't try and move the directory, but zip it up and move it as a `File.Move(src,dest);` and you can then extract it and there you have it!

Comment: It is unlikely you will end up getting any votes for this suggestion.  This answer already has an accepted answer.  Your proposed solution has the same issues as other answers but with more complexity

Comment: +1 because the directory creation dates are preserved using this approach. At least when tested using 7z.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem in VB.NET and instead of "Directory.Move" I used MoveFolder with "FileSystemObject".
You can preserve creation dates with this method.

```
Scripting.FileSystemObject oFSO = new Scripting.FileSystemObject();
oFSO.MoveFolder(sourceDirName, destDirName)
```

Answer (score 0):

i have this problem to and i like to solve it in this way

```
 string startPath = @".\start";
        string zipPath = @".\result.zip";
        string extractPath = @".\extract";

        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);

        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
```